# Referencing Parse.User in a background job

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

What I want to do is create an MComparisonArray object with a `Name` property of `MatchCenter`, an `MCItems` array property equal to the `eBayResults` array, and to have the `parent` property of this object be a pointer to the `User` object that created it, that way each `User` has their own specific `MComparisonArray` object associated with their account.

When I try to do this below, it gives me an error stating that `User` is not defined, as I expected it would. I'm unsure of how to form the syntax to tell Parse to make the object's parent property be a pointer to the `User`.

I know that if I wanted to do this from within the iOS app, I would do `('parent', Parse.User.current())`, but there is no such thing as `Parse.User.current` in a background job.

**Main Promise Chain:**

```
   Parse.Cloud.job("MatchCenterBackground", function(request, status) {
      //code to setup usersQuery ...
      var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

      return usersQuery.each(function (user) {
        return processUser(user).then(function(eBayResults){
          return matchCenterComparison(eBayResults);
        });
      }); 
    });
```

**Snippet from `matchCenterComparison` function:**

```
  var newMComparisonArray = new mComparisonArray();
  newMComparisonArray.set('Name', 'MatchCenter');
  newMComparisonArray.set('MCItems', eBayResults);
  newMComparisonArray.set('parent', Parse.User);

  // Save updated MComparisonArray  
  newMComparisonArray.save().then({
    success: function() {
      console.log('MComparisonArray successfully created!');
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('nah no MComparisonArray saving for you bro:' + error);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the user in your outer scope, but you aren't passing it into the function.

Change your calling code to pass the current user like this:

```
return matchCenterComparison(user, eBayResults);
```

Update your function definition to accept the user as the first parameter:

```
function matchCenterComparison(parentUser, eBayResults) {
    // ...
}
```

And then use that user for the parent:

```
newMComparisonArray.set('parent', parentUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add your master key? `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()`

```
Parse.Cloud.job("MatchCenterBackground", function(request, status) {
  //code to setup usersQuery ...
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

  return usersQuery.each(function (user) {
    return processUser(user).then(function(eBayResults){
      return matchCenterComparison(eBayResults);
    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Nope, doing that and setting `parent` to `Parse.User` still doesn't work.